# simple if/else statement does not seem to be working, can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Tags: if-statement

I am trying to get a simple if/else statement working.
if the number given is bigger than 5 it should print statement A, if not it should print statement B.
It keeps printing statement A no matter what.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help.

[snippet of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bu0ih.png)

Comment: You're using the string `'value'` instead of the variable `value` ;)

Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: ah so stupid! thank you for your help!